# Fancybox Showing Scroll Bars only in Windows 10 Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, fancybox-2

I have the following fancybox which appears normal in most browsers except Chrome in Windows 10. It seems that it keeps overriding my settings and automatically setting scrolling to auto and not hiding the overflow. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
$.fancybox({
            hideOnContentClick:true,
            width:330,  
            type:'iframe',
            padding:5,
            scrolling:'no',
            iframe:{scrolling:'no'},
            beforeShow: function(){
            this.height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').height();
         },
         href:"/emailprofile/showfristsetting/"
    });
```

Note that I am using the following JS and CSS files:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css

**EDIT**
The computer in which the strange scrollbars appeared was a touchscreen. I tried the suggestion here: http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/fancyapps/fancyBox/q/stackoverflow/2268330/jquery-fancybox-but-i-don39t-want-scrollbars, but it hasn't seemed to work.

Comment: Have you tried using `outerHeight(true)` instead? `this.height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').outerHeight(true);` Or maybe better, include http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css  , maybe...

Comment: Unfortunately, the same issue exists with that.